# Bitmap canvas.drawBitmap method in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, canvas, bitmap

Basically I want to replace drawcircle method with drawBitmap method. The idea is to replace the circle with an image I have imported.

Here is my resource method

```
   // Create the bitmap object using BitmapFactory
    // Access the application resource, and then retrieve the drawable
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.ball);
```

I want to change the drawcircle method and instead replace it with drawbitmap.

```
// Create a new class extended from the View class
class GameView extends View
{
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    // Constructor
    public GameView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    // Override the onDraw method of the View class to configure
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        // Configure the paint which will be used to draw the view
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        // If the game is over
        if (isLose)
        {
            paint.setColor(Color.RED);
            paint.setTextSize(40);
            canvas.drawText("Game Over", 50, 200, paint);
        }
        // Otherwise
        else
        {
            // set the color of the ball
            paint.setColor(Color.rgb(240, 240, 80));
            canvas.drawCircle(ballX, ballY, BALL_SIZE, paint);
            // set the color of the racket
            paint.setColor(Color.rgb(80, 80, 200));
            canvas.drawRect(racketX, racketY, racketX + RACKET_WIDTH,
                    racketY + RACKET_HEIGHT, paint);
        }
    }
```

I know I have to replace canvas.drawCircle somehow but every attempt I have made so far hasn't worked. 
If anybody could help that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I wish to replace the canvas.drawCircle with an image that looks like a ball rather than having just a circle drawn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following code:

```
    // set the color of the ball
    paint.setColor(Color.rgb(240, 240, 80));
    canvas.drawCircle(ballX, ballY, BALL_SIZE, paint);
```

to:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, destRect, null);
```

In the above code, bitmap refers to the one you create in your code, and desRect is an Rect that determines where to draw that bitmap. It may be calculated like this:

```
  Rect destRect = new Rect(ballX - BALL_SIZE, ballY - BALL_SIZE, ballX + BALL_SIZE, ballY + BALL_SIZE);
```

Remember to calculate it outside the onDraw method in case there is a efficiency problem.